# Extracting text and ID from in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

I am currently having trouble trying to extract some text and id numbers from some XML in one column of data.

An example:

```
<item>
<attr id="1">GOOD</attr>
<attr id="2">YELLOW </attr>
<attr id="3">18</attr>
<attr id="4">Not</attr>
<attr id="5">60</attr>
<attr id="6">NEW</attr>
</item>
```

I need to separate the ID and Text/Numbers after. I have run through some similar queries but nothing that seems to fit/work. Is there a simple way to split this data?

Ideal result:

```
ID    TEXT
1    GOOD
2    YELLOW
ETC
```

Using MySQL.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Use MySQL or other DB?

Comment: @jarlh Apologies, MySQL is correct

Comment: @Shawn.X Apologies, MySQL is correct

Comment: Which version of mysql are you using now?